# DotNet Debugging CS0579: Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, sdk

I am working on a `SDK` where we have multiple build targets. I have been running into an issue where each of the targets seems to be building assembly attributes when I have explicitly turned them off with

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework> 
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild> 
<AssemblyName>Dropbox.Api</AssemblyName> 
<RootNamespace>Dropbox.Api</RootNamespace> 
<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo> 
<GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute> 
<GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute> 
<GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute> 
<GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute> 
<GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute> 
<GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute> 
<GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
```

In the main property group of every `csproj` file

Here is the errors I am seeing:

> net45obj\Debug.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,12): error CS0579: Duplicate
> 'global::System.Runtime. Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute [dropbox-sdk-
> dotnet\dropbox-sdk-dotnet\Dropbox.Api\ Dropbox.Api.NetStandard.csproj]
> net45obj\Release.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,12): error CS0579: Duplicate
> 'global::System.Runtim e.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute [dropbox-sdk-
> dotnet\dropbox-sdk-dotnet\Dropbox.Ap i\Dropbox.Api.NetStandard.csproj]
> portable40obj\Debug.NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile344.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,12):
> error CS0579: Duplicate ' global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute
> [dropbox-sdk-dotnet\dropbox- sdk-dotnet\Dropbox.Api\Dropbox.Api.NetStandard.csproj]
> portable40obj\Release.NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile344.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,12):
> error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute
> [dropbox-sdk-dotnet\dropbo x-sdk-dotnet\Dropbox.Api\Dropbox.Api.NetStandard.csproj]
> portableobj\Debug.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,12):
> error CS0579: Duplicate 'gl obal::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute
> [dropbox-sdk-dotnet\dropbox-sd k-dotnet\Dropbox.Api\Dropbox.Api.NetStandard.csproj]
> portableobj\Release.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,12):
> error CS0579: Duplicate ' global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute
> [dropbox-sdk-dotnet\dropbox- sdk-dotnet\Dropbox.Api\Dropbox.Api.NetStandard.csproj]
> obj\Release\netstandard2.0.NETStandard,Version=v2.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,12): error CS0579:
> Duplicate 'global::Syst em.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute [dropbox-sdk-
> dotnet\dropbox-sdk-dotnet\D ropbox.Api\Dropbox.Api.NetStandard.csproj]

I am not sure if I am generating this incorrectly or if there is another way to disable this error.
For more information, I am working on the [Dropbox SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet)

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried to set `GeneratePackageOnBuild` to `false`?

```
<GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>
```

But first delete all of these assembly attributes files